# <util:properties> equivalent in java based configuration for spring

Tags: java, spring

What would be the equivalent in java based configuration of XML based spring configuration

```
<util:properties id="mapper"  location="classpath:mapper.properties" />
```

To then be able to use this specific property object in code like :

```
@Resource(name = "mapper")
private Properties myTranslator;
```

Looking at the doc, I looked at the

```
@PropertySource
```

annotation but it seems to me that the particular propertyfile will not be able to be accessed individually from the Environment object.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Very simply, declare a [`PropertiesFactoryBean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertiesFactoryBean.html).

```
@Bean(name = "mapper")
public PropertiesFactoryBean mapper() {
    PropertiesFactoryBean bean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
    bean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("com/foo/jdbc-production.properties"));
    return bean;
}
```

In the documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-util-properties), you'll notice that before they made `<util:properties>`, they used to use a `PropertiesFactoryBean` as such

```
<!-- creates a java.util.Properties instance with values loaded from the supplied location -->
<bean id="jdbcConfiguration" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
  <property name="location" value="classpath:com/foo/jdbc-production.properties"/>
</bean>
```

Converting that to Java config is super easy as shown above.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like I have still some RTFM progresses to do;-)

Comment: @YvesNicole You're welcome. I don't blame you, TFM is extremely long.

Comment: If you have web application and want to be able to read from `WEB-INF`, use `ServletContextResource`. If you want universal solution, use `ServletContextResourcePatternResolver`. Notice what you will need `ServletContext` reference in this case

Answer (score 0):

In Spring Boot 5+, application.properties under src/main/resources is the Convention. I have found if you need to put your own custom properties, for example "student.class.name", then Spring will automatically validate it in Eclipse and tag the entry with a warning, with the option to create metadata for it. Click it and it will create a JSON file under META-INF. Use that. Then you can inject the property using @Value("${student.class.name}" annotation.

Comment: are you serious?