# Using spring to load properties as System properties

Tags: spring, properties

I'm using Spring 4.1.6.
I have something like the following:

**foo.properties:**

```
valueX=a
valueY=b
```

**Spring bean:**

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:foo.properties" ignore-unresolvable="false" ignore-resource-not-found="false" />

    <bean id="foo" class="com.foo.bar.MyClass" >
        <property name="someValue" value="${valueX}" />
    </bean>
```

I have a non-Spring class which also needs to use a value from foo.properties.

**Non Spring Class:**

```
public void doSomething() {
  String valueY = System.getProperty("valueY");
}
```

When Spring loads foo.properties, is there a way to populate all the properties into System properties so that I can get "valueY" using System.getProperty("valueY").

I don't want to load foo.properties again in my non-Spring class.

Comment: How about this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339736/set-system-property-with-spring-configuration-file

Answer (score 0):

The `context:property-placeholder` will create a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` config bean for you. You cannot  access the properties from this bean programatically as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11415711/programmatic-access-to-properties-created-by-property-placeholder).

What you can do is to load the properties into a separate spring bean as given below.

```
@Bean(name = "mapper")
public PropertiesFactoryBean mapper() {
  PropertiesFactoryBean bean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
  bean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("application.properties"));
  return bean;
}
```

and then set the system property when the context load is finished using a listener as given below. Got the code from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18895839/utilproperties-equivalent-in-java-based-configuration-for-spring)

```
@Component
public class YourJobClass implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    @Resource(name = "mapper")
    private Properties myTranslator;

    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent contextRefreshedEvent) {
        System.setProperties(myTranslator);
    }
}
```